# Dealing with multiple textures on an object

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I imagine images will explain what I've got better than I have the words for, so here's what I'm working with: [image]

I have 3 albedos I want to put on this model and bake. I have no idea how to go about this, since I'm used to Maya. I would usually just copy and paste the existing UV setup onto a new UV map, but it seems blender doesn't have the same UV editing capabilities.

And... yes, I know it's abhorrent to have 3 textures on a single character. It's for an online game with set standards for user created content and this is it. :/

Comment: What exactly is not working? There are plenty of tutorials about baking.

Comment: You don't need 3 copies of the UVs, just create 3 different materials that use the same one. The basic way to use more than one material on the same mesh is detailed here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: @Dimali The UVs are outside of the texture range, so it bakes a transparent image if those parts are being baked. The torso and arms, which are in the range, bake fine.

Comment: You can create as many [uv maps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_management.html) as you want, the highlighted map is the one being edited in the uv image editor. Each image texture can use a different uv map to show on different parts of the model, the render engine you are using will determine how to set that up.